# Apache Mina SFTP 2.8.0 Upgrade

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina, apache-sshd

I am trying to upgrade 0.14.0 sshd-core and 0.11.0 sshd-sftp to 2.8.0 version.

Unfortunately I found that there are a lot of implementation changes, but I did not find a migration guide before version 2.0.0 (It would be great if someone could provide me with a migration guide from 0.11.0/0.14.0 to 2.0.0)

The main problem I have is the lack of FileSystemView and SshFile since the previous version has file system independence and we use the ability for the root sub-directory of both Windows and Unix to be '/'.
Now, when I try to run sftp server on Windows the Windows file system always redirects me to 'C:\'.

I would be extremely grateful for some ideas on how I can migrate to the new version given the file system problem.